# Javascript: how can I access a class property to a function inside nested object

Tags: javascript

I'm working with javascript classes and there's something I want to do but I don't know how. First of all, this is my class:

```
class Company {
  constructor (options) {
    this.employee = options.employee;
    this.algorithm = "AZ1";
  }
}
```

Now, employee is an object which has another object nested inside of it and that final object contains a series of functions:

```
employee {
  code {
    generate [Function: generate]
    alter [Function: alter]
  }
}
```

Now, my problem is that I want to access the `algorithm` from any of these functions?

Btw; I'm trying to do so from an object created with that class:

```
const myCompany = new Company({ employee });
```

So I want to access the `algorithm` property from the generate function within `myCompany`.

Comment: `this.employee.code.generate(this.algorithm)` Like this?

Comment: Sorry i've explained myself wrong. English is not my native tongue so i get nervous, let me edit it

Comment: Did you intend for `constructors` to be plural?

Comment: It was a typo here in stackoverflow. Either way, that solution work but i'll like it to be invisible for the user so it doesn't have to pass that value.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the algorithm like this: `myCompany.employee.code.generate(myCompany.algorithm)`

EDIT: It wasn't clear from your original question that you're trying to keep the algorithm private to the class. Something like this might work:

```js
class Company {
  constructor (options) {
    this.employee = options.employee;
    this.algorithm = "AZ1";
  }

  generateEmployee = () => {
    this.employee.code.generate(this.algorithm);
  }
}
```

This would give you a `myCompany.generateEmployee` method that the caller could use without passing in the algorithm.

Note that this syntax will only work if you're using a transpiler like Babel. If not, you can use this syntax (so your method has the right `this` context):

```js
class Company {
  constructor (options) {
    this.employee = options.employee;
    this.algorithm = "AZ1";
    this.generateEmployee = this.generateEmployee.bind(this);
  }

  generateEmployee() {
    this.employee.code.generate(this.algorithm);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've edited the question. Sorry; either way, I have to pass that value every single time? I would like it to be invisible to the users who call these functions

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I've edited my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

`object1.field1 = object2` is a one-way relation:

- `object1` can access `object2` afterwards, via `field1`
- `object2` has absolutely no clue about `object1` being around, and thus it can not know about its other fields either.

You can pass it as an argument, like `object1.field1.dosomething(object1.field2)`, which in the actual case translates to:

```
myCompany.employee.code.generate(myCompany.algorithm)
```

(And of course assumes that `generate()` is modified to expect such argument. The freshly added `option` does not affect the pattern)

Comment: Is there another way to access this without passing it? I won't mind changing these piece of code at all for an alternative

Comment: @EnriqueBermúdez the company-constructor could "register" itself right into the `code`, like `this.employee.code.employerUltraHack=this;`, and then it would be visible as `this.employerUltraHack` from `generate()` and the others. But it is really a hack, it assumes a single employer at a time, and causes difficulties when a company object is removed, but the employees remain.